# How to insert category(s) name in the product title?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible when I am creating new product in backend, and when I choose category of product it will write category name to product title?

So when is product title blank, and I choose category T-Shirt it will do product title “T-shirt”?

Comment: If you're worried about the front end display (not trying to get whatever category you've just selected added to the title field when editing a post, though you could do that, too), then you have to consider whether you want it added to ALL instances (for instance, when displaying the same category's acrhive), and also how you want to handle multiple categories - unless you're committed to a 1 title per category approach... Also, do you just want the category name printed, or do you want additional punctuation or even a link to the category separately from the rest of the title?..

Comment: I want to insert 1st category which selected in the product creating page & the product link will generate by the title. Suppose category name 'Beauty & Fashion' which I selected. So the product URL should need to be 'http://www.mysitename.com.product/beauty-fashion'

Comment: One additional question: Is this to apply to ALL products in ALL places, or just certain products in all or some places, etc?. If you don't want to apply the change to all products wherever their titles appear, what are the exceptions - alternatively, can you group them together in some way, like "all with the same parent category" or some such?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you would like to automatically fill the product title field with the name of the first category you select for that product.

You can achieve that with a little script that first checks if the product title field is empty and then checks how many categories are selected for this product. If the product title field is empty and there is only one category selected it will automatically fill the product title field with this category.
So if you create a new product the first category you select will fill the product title field. All categories you select after that will have no effect.

Add the following code snippet to the functions.php of your **child theme** or via a plugin like [Code Snippets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/):

```
//Add first selected product category to product title field if empty
add_action('admin_head', 'add_first_selected_category_to_product_title');
function add_first_selected_category_to_product_title() {
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery( function( $ ) {
            $('.post-type-product #product_catchecklist input[type=checkbox]').click( function () {
                
                //Check if post title is empty and if only one category is selected
                if( $('.post-type-product #product_catchecklist').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length === 1 && $('.post-type-product #title').val().length === 0 ) {
                    
                    //If so, add the category to the product title
                    $('.post-type-product #product_catchecklist input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
                        if (this.checked) {
                            let $category = $(this).closest('label').text();
                            $('#title-prompt-text').html('');
                            $('.post-type-product #title').val($category);
                        }
                    });

                }

            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: If this answer works for you could you [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thank you in advance.